# Does Votive support Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, votive

I want to use Votive with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate I want to know if it is supported with it. I have Wix 3.5 and Windows Installer 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked and the integration is provided for all the releases beginning with VS 2005,VS 2008, VS11 Beta , VS2010,VS2012 RC.